# Issue setting data for Radar Chart in iOS charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the charting library here https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/ however I am having a couple of issues.

First, I have no idea how to set the data for a radar chart type and second, I have an error when apply the RadarChart to uiview. The error is

```
Unknown class RadarChartView in Interface Builder file.
```

The app still runs and I can see an empty uiview.

I have looked at the demo app and through the documentation but I am still unsure how to actually set any data to the chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at ChartsDemo app, why you still not unsure how to use it? The code is straightforward. Otherwise I am still copy pasting code from ChartsDemo, which is meaningless.

For the class, you need to choose Charts module for your IB: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/59

1. downloaded library
2. reembedded it with the option "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code"
3. In Storyboard where I defined the class for the charts view as "LineChartView", I also have to set the module manually to "Charts".